# SQL LEFT JOIN IS NULL over multiple columns

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, left-join

I am using Microsoft Access 2007 and found that this SQL does not have the **EXCEPT** operator. I learned that I can use **LEFT JOIN** and **IS NULL** to perform this operation. I almost have it but can't quite put my thumb on it.

I have two tables, Table A has data of a personID, foodID, and timePURCHASED. A person with an ID buys food of ID at a certain time. Table B is a subset of that. (It has selected rows from Table A.)

My goal is to do: Table A EXCEPT Table B.

Table A

<kbd>personID</kbd><kbd>foodID</kbd><kbd>timePURCHASED</kbd>             
<kbd>1</kbd>            <kbd>1</kbd>         <kbd>2/6/2012 1:00:00 PM</kbd>        

<kbd>1</kbd>            <kbd>4</kbd>         <kbd>2/6/2012 6:00:00 PM</kbd>        

<kbd>2</kbd>            <kbd>3</kbd>         <kbd>2/7/2012 8:00:00 PM</kbd>        

<kbd>3</kbd>            <kbd>1</kbd>         <kbd>2/6/2012 9:00:00 PM</kbd>        

<kbd>3</kbd>            <kbd>3</kbd>         <kbd>2/6/2012 4:00:00 PM</kbd>

Table B

<kbd>personID</kbd><kbd>foodID</kbd><kbd>timePURCHASED</kbd>             
<kbd>1</kbd>            <kbd>1</kbd>         <kbd>2/6/2012 1:00:00 PM</kbd>        

<kbd>3</kbd>            <kbd>3</kbd>         <kbd>2/6/2012 4:00:00 PM</kbd>

GOAL

<kbd>personID</kbd><kbd>foodID</kbd><kbd>timePURCHASED</kbd>             


<kbd>1</kbd>            <kbd>4</kbd>         <kbd>2/6/2012 6:00:00 PM</kbd>        

<kbd>2</kbd>            <kbd>3</kbd>         <kbd>2/7/2012 8:00:00 PM</kbd>        

<kbd>3</kbd>            <kbd>1</kbd>         <kbd>2/6/2012 9:00:00 PM</kbd>

Here is my code I started:

```
SELECT A.personID, A.foodID, A.timePURCHASED  
FROM A  
LEFT JOIN B ON (A.personID = B.personID)   
WHERE ((B.personID) Is Null);
```

I understand that this will result in my GOAL table not having any matching personID (1, 3) and leave behind personID not matched (2). I understand that I need to consider all three columns at the same time and found that I can use the **AND** operator in my **LEFT JOIN**:

```
SELECT A.personID, A.foodID, A.timePURCHASED  
FROM A  
LEFT JOIN B ON (A.personID = B.personID)  
AND (A.foodID = B.foodID)  
AND (A.timePURCHASED = B.timePURCHASED)  
WHERE (((B.personID) Is Null)  
AND ((B.foodID) Is Null)  
AND ((B.timePURCHASED) Is Null));
```

So far this has not worked and I am looking for some advice. I apologize for the format, TLDR, or if this is something easier to answer. I am a novice and learning SQL. Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Could the reason that it has _not worked_ be the unbalanced `)` after `A.timePURCHASES = B.timePURCHASED`? Also, you only have to check for one of the columns from B being NULL.

Comment: Sorry, typo. Had to learn how to format the post as well. Corrected.

Comment: How does your query not work?  (Syntax error? To many rows returned? Missing rows in result? , ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second query generally looks good. You don't need all 3 `IS NULL` checks, though, since you don't have any nulls in your input set. You can also get rid of all those parentheses.

```
SELECT A.personID, A.foodID, A.timePurchased 
  FROM A 
  LEFT JOIN B 
  ON A.personID = B.personID
    AND A.foodID = B.foodID
    AND A.timePurchased = B.timePurchased
  WHERE B.personID is null;
```

This works perfectly (meaning it outputs exactly the "GOAL" relation you specify) on a brand-new database I set up from your specifications, but so does your second query.

So it seems like something must be wrong with the setup, not with the SQL itself. What does your `CREATE TABLE` statement look like for these two tables? Specifically, what are the data types that you are comparing? Are the `timePURCHASED` columns strings under the hood? If so, do they have spaces in them? Does one table have strings and the other `DATETIME`s? And to Terje D.'s point, what *precisely* is the result you're seeing?

Comment: Thank you for replying, as far as I understood it the query should work, but I am thinking it may be the timePURCHASED. For my results, I am getting all the rows in Table A. 

I am going to look to see if they are strings.

Comment: Alright, I figured it out. So it was not a problem with the code I had. Though, I did clean it up to your suggestion.

The problem I had was how I created Table B. While I did everything correct to query the rows I needed, I unnecessarily did a 

    GROUP BY A.personID, A.foodID, A.timePURCHASED

Without this line I still get the same data for Table B, erasing this and reevaluating my query fixed my results. I am not sure exactly why, but I think it "grouped" them somehow where they were not the same elements? Any light on this would help. Thank you again for all your help.